# Qt - A simple echo server

Tags: c++, qt4, qthread, qtcpserver

How in Qt would you keep a thread alive in the QThreadPool; as far as I've seen there is only an option to run a QRunnable and I've been told they can't control the thread they are within. How would I, using the thread pool keep a socket alive and ready to read and write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QThreadPool](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qthreadpool.html) manages its own threads. QT Doc says that

> QThreadPool manages and recyles
>   individual QThread objects to help
>   reduce thread creation costs in
>   programs that use threads.

So you should not try to keep a thread alive. That breaks the purpose of thread pool.

Also QT sockets are designed to work well with the main event loop. Why don't you try using them ?

Answer (score 0):

a) Just use a QThread descendant, rather than a threadpool.

b) Don't tie sockets to threads - when select() returns, assign a thread to handle the socket event.

Rgds,
Martin